# Error when building after adding spritefont to monogame

Tags: monogame

When I through the monogame pipeline tool add either an existing or a new spritefont, I get two errors when I try to build the solution.

> The command *'input dir'* *'output dir'* exited with code -532462766.

And

> Processor 'FontDescriptionProcessor' had unexpected failure! *'path to
>   spritefont'*

Any idea why this can be?

Comment: Perhaps it couldn't locate where the spritefont is found?

Comment: You are not getting any errors when you are building through the pipeline itself?